# How do Word-of-Faith and Pentecostal churches interpret Romans 12 when Paul says to think "according to the measure of faith that God has assigned"

Tags: exegesis, faith, romans, pentecostalism, word-of-faith

The little personal interaction I've had with [Word-of-Faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_of_Faith) and Pentecostal churches is that they believe that with enough faith God can and will do anything through you.

Is my summary correct? If so, how then do they interpret [Romans 12:3-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2012%3A3-7&version=ESV):

> **Romans 12:3-6 (ESV)** - For by the grace given to me I say to everyone among you not to think of himself more highly than he ought to think, but to think with sober judgment, ***each according to the measure of faith that God has assigned***. For as in one body we have many members, and the members do not all have the same function, so we, though many, are one body in Christ, and individually members one of another. Having gifts that differ according to the grace given to us, let us use them: if prophecy, in proportion to our faith;

It seems to say that God gives us a measure of faith and that we should work inside of that.

Comment: When you say word of faith churches are you specifically referring to the Wof movement as described in the following site?  https://www.apologeticsindex.org/4914-word-faith-movement  Or you want to know the actual meaning of the text of Romans 12:3-6? I'm just asking for clarity.

Comment: @Mr.Bond I think the OP wants to see how the WoF community would respond to non-WoF Christian's using Rom 12:3-6 as a rebuttal for the WoF core doctrine that says: enough faith can prompt God to do anything through you.  BTW, your link is quite good on how to talk to someone who is being misguided by WoF.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple You got it.